# how can I implement another volley request inside a volley request

Tags: android, android-volley, android-spinner

I am currently trying to develop a simple messaging app.. In the compose part of the message, an api is used to send the composed message while there is spinner to choose the contacts, so I need to get the values from another api as items in spinner. So, how can I implement another volley request inside a volley request?

Answer (score 1):

Write the other volley request within the response of the first volley request.

Comment: This might sound stupid but, is it the best way to make multiple requests? Is there some best practice documentation you could share? Thanks

Comment: It depends, are you intending to make those requests as a chain(i.e. perform second request after first request is done) or independent?.  If it is the latter, you will need to set priority to your requests.  Also do make sure to follow singleton pattern to access your requests queue and for cache.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped you feel free to accept it as answer so it could help others.